# List pods that are servicing a service

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, kubernetes-helm, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to get the list of pods that are servicing a particular service

There are 3 pods associated with my service.

I tried to execute the below command

`oc describe svc my-svc-1`

I am expecting to see the pods associated with this service. but that does not show up. What command gets me just the list of pods associated with the service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A service chooses the pods using the selector. Look at the selector for the service, and get the pods using that selector. For kubectl, the command looks like:

```
kubectl get pods --selector <selector>
```

Comment: Another question, Can you suggest how do i list the services ending with a certain string. i am trying to do this ```oc get services --name "*dev"``` and it didnt work

Comment: I do not know a built-in mechanism to do that. I'd use grep for such things.